# Get unsolved array keys of product data tabs in woo product editor page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I can get array keys of product data tabs in woo product editor page by this code `var_dump( array_keys( $tabs ) );`, so I can hide them. But I could not solve the array keys of couple tabs that created by plugin and build in tab by the theme (flatsome). Any help really appreciate it. Thank you.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs' , 'block_wc_product_tabs' );

function block_wc_product_tabs($tabs) {

      if (!current_user_can('yith_vendor')) {  // replace role ID with your own
          return $tabs;
      }

      var_dump( array_keys( $tabs ) );
      //unset($tabs['general']);
      //unset($tabs['inventory']);
      unset($tabs['linked_product']);
      unset( $tabs['tm_extra_product_options'] );
      //unset( $tabs['product_origin'] );

      return $tabs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the order of execution of your action.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs' , 'block_wc_product_tabs', 9999  );

function block_wc_product_tabs($tabs) {

      if (!current_user_can('yith_vendor')) {  // replace role ID with your own
          return $tabs;
      }

      var_dump( array_keys( $tabs ) );
      //unset($tabs['general']);
      //unset($tabs['inventory']);
      unset($tabs['linked_product']);
      unset( $tabs['tm_extra_product_options'] );
      //unset( $tabs['product_origin'] );

      return $tabs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

below the code used by the plugin to add the tab in product data tabs

```
function epeken_product_write_panel_tab() {
                echo "<li class=\"product_tabs_lite_tab\"><a href=\"#woocommerce_product_tabs_lite\">" . __( 'Epeken Product Config', 'woocommerce' ) . "</a></li>";
        }

        function epeken_product_write_panel() {
        global $post;
        if(epeken_is_multi_vendor_mode()) {
            //do nothing if multi vendor mode is true
            ?>
            <div id="woocommerce_product_tabs_lite" class="panel wc-metaboxes-wrapper woocommerce_options_panel" style="padding: 10px;">
                        <table>
                <tr><td>
            <p>Toko Online Anda berkonsep marketplace. Untuk menerapkan konsep marketplace, pastikan license Anda dilengkapi opsi multi origin. Anda dapat melakukan setting kota asal di level vendor/seller/pelapak sehingga produk ini dapat mengikuti kota asal vendornya. <a href="http://blog.epeken.com/plugin-epeken-support-plugin-marketplace/" target="_blank">Selengkapnya</a></p>
                </td></tr></table>
            </div>
            <?php
            return;
        }
        $epeken_product_config = array (
            "product_origin" => get_post_meta($post->ID,'product_origin',true)
        );
```